# Visual Force Page to display live agents in one page

Tags: apex, visualforce, liveagent

I'd like to have a Visual Force Page that displays all my online live agents in one view.

I want the names of each of the agents who are "online" to be displayed on a single screen. I'm not certain if its possible to do that. If it is, how would I go about it setting it up or creating the page?

Answer (score 1):

i think this is what your looking for

its called live agent supervisor

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=live_agent_supervisor_panel.htm&language=en_US